# Pass dir.path to a diferent script

Tags: python, properties, panel

I'm building an addon which is a collection of scripts, and I have my UI coded as one of this scripts. On of my tools (script) requires a user input, in this case a folder path, but I don`t know how to pass it onto my export tool so it knows where to export the selected objects. Here is how it is written in my UI script, I just copied it:

```
# root for export
    scn = context.scene
    col = layout.column(align=True)
    col.prop(scn.my_tool, "path", text="")
```

It shows great in my Panel but I'm not sure how use the string it gives in another script.

Thanks

EDIT

Following @WhataMesh pointed out here is what I did. In my UI script I added a class with a string property and changed the layout to fit, also had to register and unregister the new class and the property.

```
class MySettings(PropertyGroup):

path = StringProperty(
    name="path",
    description="Path to Directory",
    default="",
    maxlen=1024,
    subtype='DIR_PATH'


def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

# root for export
    scn = context.scene
    mytool = scn.my_tool
    col = layout.column(align=True)
    col.prop(mytool, "path", text="")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(UI)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MySettings)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MySettings)



def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(UI)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MySettings)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add properties to the scene that can be retrieved by all scripts. In the code you can find different 'variabletypes' (I think you can also make custom properties/variables yourself). To actually retrieve the value you will have to write `bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].Annotation.my_bool`

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import (StringProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       IntProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       PointerProperty,
                       )
from bpy.types import (Panel,
                       Operator,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       )

class Annotation(PropertyGroup):
    my_bool = BoolProperty(
        name="Enable or Disable",
        description="A bool property",
        default=False
    )

    my_int = IntProperty(
        name="Int Value",
        description="A integer property",
        default=23,
        min=10,
        max=100
    )

    my_float = FloatProperty(
        name="Float Value",
        description="A float property",
        default=23.7,
        min=0.01,
        max=30.0
    )

    my_string = StringProperty(
        name="User Input",
        description=":",
        default="",
        maxlen=1024,
    )

    my_enum = EnumProperty(
        name="Dropdown:",
        description="Apply Data to attribute.",
        items=[('OP1', "Option 1", ""),
               ('OP2', "Option 2", ""),
               ('OP3', "Option 3", ""),
               ]
    )

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.Annotation = PointerProperty(type=Annotation)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.Annotation
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, this class should go with my UI script? and once done calling any variable (for instance my_string) in any other script it will be read?

Comment: @JuanManuelLynch Yes

Comment: For a folder path can use `path = StringProperty(subtype='DIR_PATH')`  Which will give folder selection widget in ui.  Worth noting with 2.8 around the corner `bpy.utils.register_module(...)` has been phased out in 2.8. Instead use `register_class(...)` on a per class basis.

Comment: @WhatAMesh it took me a while to make it work as I think that the register function is not correct as you state it and also how you call it didn't work. Still I managed to make it work. Check my edited question to see if I actually undestood what I'm doing.